# HTTP ERROR 500 while running google app engine application on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /. Reason:
>
> ```
> java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 51 in method todo.Dao.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V at offset 5 ......
> ```

the above mentioned is the error I am getting, I ve tried to add the new default variable  -XX:-UseSplitVerifier in " Window -> Preferences -> Installed JREs -> and add the default parameter." still getting the same error. Please help if anyone know something regarding this issue

Best Regards 
MDG

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by including the a build.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<target name="help" description="Lists different targets in the build file">
    <echo>Target             --- Description</echo>
    <echo>------------------------------------------------------</echo>
    <echo>copyjars           --- Copies the App Engine JARs to the WAR</echo>
    <echo>compile            --- Compiles Java source files and copies other source files to the WAR.</echo>
    <echo>datanucleusenhance --- Performs JDO enhancement on compiled data classes.</echo>
    <echo>runserver          --- Starts the development server.</echo>
    <echo>update_indexes     --- Uploads just the datastore index configuration to App Engine.</echo>
    <echo>rollback           --- Rolls back an interrupted application update.</echo>
    <echo>request_logs       --- Downloads log data from App Engine for the application.</echo>
</target>
```